# Proof: Show that for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha\neq0$, there exists a unique $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha\beta=1$

Tags: solution-verification, complex-numbers

Trying to prove the statement in the title and wondering if I did it correctly. Any feedback would be helpful. I am assuming all properties of the reals.

Before I can do the main proof, I must first prove that the multiplicative-communitative property holds with complex numbers.

> Show that $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$ for every $\alpha$, $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$.

Suppose
$$\alpha = a + bi$$
and
$$\beta = c + di$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then
\begin{align} \alpha\beta &= (a+bi)(c+di) \\
&= (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i
\end{align}
(by definition of complex multiplication) and
\begin{align} \beta\alpha &= (c+di)(a+bi) \\
&= (ca-db)+(da+cb)i \\ \text{ (by def} &\text{inition of complex multiplication)} \\
&= (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i.
\end{align}

Therefore, $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$ for every $\alpha$, $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$.

**Now onto the main proof:**

> Show that for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha\neq0$,there exists a unique $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha\beta=1$.

I need to prove two things for this to be true:

1. For every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha\neq0$, there exists a $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha\beta=1$.
2. For every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha\neq0$, there exists a *unique* $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha\beta=1$.

Suppose
$$\alpha = a + bi$$
and
$$\beta = c + di$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then
\begin{align} \alpha\beta &= (a+bi)(c+di) \\
&= (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i
\end{align}
(by definition of complex multiplication.)
(Since $a$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$, $\frac{a}{a^2+b^2} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2} \in \mathbb{R}$, so set $c = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$ and $d =\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}$.)
\begin{align} 
&= \left(a\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}-b\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}\right)+\left(a\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}+b\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}\right)i \\
&= \left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}\right)+\left(\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}\right)i \\
&= \left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2}\right)+\left(\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}\right)i \\
&= 1+0i = 1+0=1.
\end{align}

Now suppose $\beta_1 = \left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}\right) + \left(\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}\right)i$ and $\beta_2$ is a different multiplicative inverse of $\alpha$. This means that
$$\alpha\beta_1 = 1$$
and
$$\alpha\beta_2 = 1.$$

By multiplying both sides of the second equation by $\beta_1$, you get
$$\beta_1\alpha\beta_2 = \beta_11.$$

$\beta_1\alpha =\alpha\beta_1$ by the communitative property, so this simplifies to
$$1\beta_2 = \beta_2 = \beta_1.$$

Therefore, for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha \neq 0$, there exists a unique $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha\beta = 1$.

Comment: I think your proof is just fine! Not really much of an answer on my part, just commenting that your proof appears to be good. There is a unique multiplicative inverse of any complex number because you can write down the function for it, and since it's a function, outputs are unique.

Comment: What you have done is to derive $1/\alpha=\alpha^*/\alpha\alpha^*=\frac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2}$